# Cannot detect Browser when using Elastic Load Balancer

Tags: amazon-web-services, load-balancing, amazon-elb, internet-explorer

*Note: I have asked the same question on [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66150583/cannot-detect-browser-when-using-elastic-load-balancer) but I though it might be more relevant to this forum.*

---

I want to prevent users from using my website in Internet Explorer.

What I want to do is to detect their browser on the server side, and if it is Internet Explorer, I would redirect them to a page, saying "IE is not supported"

I have tried detecting browser using both `Browser` and `UserAgent`, in the development environment, I get the following values:

```
var browser = HttpContext.Current.Request.Browser;     // <-- InternetExplorer
var userAgent = HttpContext.Current.Request.UserAgent; // <-- Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64; Trident/7.0; rv:11.0) like Gecko
```

But when I run the same code in my test environment (test server is behind Application Load Balancer) I get the following values:

```
var browser = HttpContext.Current.Request.Browser;     // <-- Unknown
var userAgent = HttpContext.Current.Request.UserAgent; // <-- ELB-HealthChecker/2.0
```

I am not sure if Application Load Balancer removes the `UserAgent` header? And if so, how to prevent it?

Comment: It looks like you are inspecting a health check request, not a request from a web browser. Look at a different request.

Comment: @MichaelHampton: thanks, the only other value that I can see has User-Agent = `Amazon CloudFront`

Comment: @MichaelHampton: thanks for your help... After whitelisting `User-Agent` header in CloudFront, the values are coming through